# Not able to send email from Linux command line interface using "mailx"

Tags: shell

command :

`- $mail -s "This is the subject" someone@example.com`

> Error:-Nov 28 20:57:43 cu1 postfix/qmgr[10441]: 07D0478D01:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=6417, delays=6417/0/0/0,
>   dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or
>   domain name not found. Name service error for name=hcl.com type=MX:
>   Host not found, try again)

Comment: can you `dig` and `nslookup` your domain ?

Comment: I am not able to do so. please the below out put:-
0112:~ # nslookup 10.14.135.155
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

0112:~ # dig 10.14.135.155

; <<>> DiG 9.3.4 <<>> 10.14.135.155
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Answer (score 0):

The domain name **hcl.com** is not found in DNS,

Try adding a **nameserver** to **/etc/resolv.conf** which can resolve the domain name or try using the ***IP*** itself (if available) for SMTP(as mail server hostname).

Comment: cu1:~/Manoj # /etc/init.d/postfix status
Checking for service Postfix:                                         unused
cu1:~/Manoj # /etc/init.d/postfix start
Starting mail service (Postfix)                                       done
cu1:~/Manoj # nslookup 10.14.25.113
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

You have new mail in /var/mail/root
cu1:~/Manoj # ping 10.14.25.113
PING 10.14.25.113 (10.14.25.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.14.25.113: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=13.9 ms

Comment: I am able to ping to SMTP server however i did get output for nslookup command.

Comment: if the IP is reachable, have you tried the IP for smtp/snmp mail server hostname instead of hostname hcl.com